# Catch exception strategy inside choice exception strategy

Tags: mule

I do not see the method causeMatches in exception context of caught expression strategy. I get an error at run time.
Where do I find the available methods in the exception context object ? I could not find one in the api documentation - http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.8.3/apidocs/

```
ERROR 2017-05-08 20:20:05,348 [[american-flights-ws].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception 
in Exception Strategy: Execution of the expression "exception.causeMatches('com.mulesoft.weave.*')" failed.
org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "exception.causeMatches('com.mulesoft.weave.*')" failed.
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluateInternal(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:232) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:163) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.evaluate(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:142) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:216) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluateBoolean(DefaultExpressionManager.java:417) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluateBoolean(DefaultExpressionManager.java:674) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.exception.TemplateMessagingExceptionStrategy.accept(TemplateMessagingExceptionStrategy.java:191) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.exception.ChoiceMessagingExceptionStrategy.handleException(ChoiceMessagingExceptionStrategy.java:55) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$3$1.execute(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:131) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.executeCallback(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:144) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.access$000(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$3.responseSentWithFailure(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:125) ~[mule-core-3.8.3.jar:3.8.3]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.doBuildResponse(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:129) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.3.jar:3.8.
3]
```

Comment: Please post your xml config ?

Answer (score 0):

Without your xml it's just guessing why it fails. But this is a working exception strategy:

```
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice_Exception_Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causeMatches('com.mulesoft.weave.*')" doc:name="Catch Weave">
            <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causeMatches('java.lang.Exception')" doc:name="Catch other">
            <logger message="#[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

In doubt, read the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/catch-exception-strategy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the choice exception strategy. There are no compilation error.But syntax seem to be a bit different.

```
<choice-exception-strategy name="ImplementationChoice_Exception_Strategy">
    <catch-exception-strategy
        when="#[exception.causeMatches('com.mule.weave.*') || exception.message=='Payload is empty.']"
        doc:name="No flights DW exception">
        <set-payload value="No flights too #[flowVars.code + '\n' + exception]"
            doc:name="Set Payload" />
        <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="400"
            doc:name="Property" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <set-payload value="data is not available, try later #['\n' + exception]"
            doc:name="Set Payload" />
        <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="500"
            doc:name="Property" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</choice-exception-strategy>
```